# Data structures in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have groups variables which have the same names. I don't want to set them unique names. So I'd like to create structure something like this:

```
 data = 
   [1] =>
      var_1 = value_1
      var_2 = value_2
      var_3 = value_3
    [2] =>
      var_1 = value_1
      var_2 = value_2
      var_3 = value_3
    [3] =>
      var_1 = value_1
      var_2 = value_2
      var_3 = value_3
```

and call them for example data[i].var_1
how can I do this with matlab syntax?

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166438/how-do-i-define-a-structure-in-matlab/4169216#4169216