# How to create matrix from struct

Tags: matlab, matrix, structure, cell-array

I have a structure `PI{1x50cell}` with fields `x`, `y`, `z`, `xy`, `t`, `des`.

`x`, `y`, `z`, `xy`, `t` are doubles. However, `des` is a 1x640 vector.

I would like to have this mapped on a two matrix, the first one will be 50x5 and the second one will be 50x640.

How to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have a 1x50 cell-array, and each cell contains a single struct?

Comment: yes PI is  1x50 cell-array and  each cell conatins a single struct where there is the fields x, y, z, xy, t, des.

Comment: May I ask why aren't you using an [array of structures](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/24/working-with-arrays-of-structures/) instead?

Comment: Borderline down-vote: Have you attempted anything yourself?

Comment: you might also find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4169216/97160

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
%# sample 1x50 cellarray, each element is a struct
PI = repmat({struct('x',1,'y',2,'z',3,'xy',4,'t',5,'des',rand(1,640))}, [1,50]);

%# create an array of structs
C = [PI{:}];

%# extract fields and build M1 a 50x5 matrix, and M2 a 50x640 matrix
M1 = [vertcat(C.x) vertcat(C.y) vertcat(C.z) vertcat(C.xy) vertcat(C.t)];
M2 = vertcat(C.des);
```