# Sort a structure of arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, structure

I have a structure of arrays `StockInfo` in Matlab. The fields of the structure  `StockInfo` are as follows:

```
StockInfo = 

      Name: {10x1 cell}
    Values: [10x6 double]
    Return: [10x1 double]
```

I need to sort `StockInfo` based on the field `Return`, so that each array in the struct is sorted accordingly. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: your problem is not well defined. You have a structure array, where each structure is as shown. If you want to sort the struct array, then it must be done based on a scalar value for each element not an array... Please clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort structure arrays based on fields with the FileExchange function `nestedSortStruct` ([link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28573-nested-sort-of-structure-arrays)).

```
B = nestedSortStruct(A, 'Return');
```

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comment above, you question is unclear. I think you are confusing structures and structure arrays. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169216/97160) might be of help.

That said, here is an example to show what I think you meant to do.

First I create a **structure array** with some random data:

```
% cell array of 10 names
names = arrayfun(@(k) randsample(['A':'Z' 'a':'z' '0':'9'],k), ...
    randi([5 10],[10 1]), 'UniformOutput',false);

% 10x6 matrix of values
values = rand(10,6);

% 10x1 vector of values
returns = randn(10,1);

% 10x1 structure array
StockInfo = struct('Name',names, 'Values',num2cell(values,2), ...
    'Return',num2cell(returns));
```

The created variable is a an array of structures:

```
>> StockInfo
StockInfo = 
10x1 struct array with fields:
    Name
    Values
    Return
```

where each element is a structure with the following fields:

```
>> StockInfo(1)
ans = 
      Name: 'Pr3N4LTEi'
    Values: [0.7342 0.1806 0.7458 0.8044 0.6838 0.1069]
    Return: -0.3818
```

Next can sort this struct array by the "return" field (each struct has a corresponding scalar value):

```
[~,ord] = sort([StockInfo.Return]);
StockInfo = StockInfo(ord);
```

The result is that the array is now sorted by the "return" values in ascending order:

```
>> [StockInfo.Return]
ans =
  Columns 1 through 8
   -0.3818    0.4289   -0.2991   -0.8999    0.6347    0.0675   -0.1871    0.2917
  Columns 9 through 10
    0.9877    0.3929
```

Comment: Note: `struct(..)` treats cell arrays as special, that's why the above creates a 10x1 array of structures, not a structure with arrays in its fields. So, if `returns` was supplied rather than `num2cell(returns)`, the result would be different (each struct in the array would have a "Return" field containing a 10x1 array, each being a copy of the original `returns`).

Comment: Note: calling a field of an array of structures (like `StockInfo.Return`) gives a comma-separated list of the elements of those structures. Therefore, `[StockInfo.Return]` gives an array. This is then sorted by `sort(..)`, which returns the permutations `ord`. To sort strings, one would say `sort({StockInfo.Name})`, but that only works for strings at the moment, until a future version of Matlab.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: yes thank you for the clarification. `s = struct('a',{11,22});` (note the cell-array) is a [special syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) to create an array of structures equivalent to: `s(1).a=11; s(2).a=22;`. Now when this array is dot-indexed, it return what is called a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). So `[s.a]` from the previous code would expand into `[s(1).a, s(2).a]`. We could also capture the list into a cell-array `{s.a}`, or even into multiple output variables `[s1,s2] = s.a;`

Comment: Many thanks for this quick guide to struct sorting! I prefer to use raw code instead of premades from File Exchange

Answer (score 1):

A solution with built-in functions only could be:

```
[~, ix] = sort(StockInfo.Return);
StockInfo = struct(...
    'Name', {StockInfo.Name{ix}}, ...
    'Values', StockInfo.Values(ix), ...
    'Return', StockInfo.Return(ix));
```

Replace ~ with any unused identifier if your Matlab is older and does not support unused output arguments.

Comment: Second line just needs to be StockInfo = StockInfo(ix)

Comment: @Trashman, Name is a `cell` array. If I do StockInfo(ix), I'll get a cell, while I want to get a string.