# flatten a struct of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers

Tags: matlab, vector, struct, flatten

Is it possible to flatten an array of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers in Matlab? For example,

```
[[1,2,[3]],4] -> [1,2,3,4]
```

Any kind of guidance will be helpful. Thanks.
For example,

```
a.c = [5,4];
a.b.a=[9];
a.b.d=[1,2];

a= b: [1x1 struct]
   c: [5 4]
```

In this case, my output will be

```
output= [9,1,2,5,4]
```

Comment: Your example array is not MATLAB syntax (or if it is, then both sides are identical so `isequal([[1,2,[3]],4],[1,2,3,4]))` would return `true`) so it's difficult to answer this properly. Can you provide a proper MATLAB example? You can probably do this using `reshape` or `(:)` but the correct answer will depend on your data-type

Comment: I have edited it. Hopefully its clear now.

Comment: That is a very different question. How should the algorithm decide on order between `.c` and `.b` and then again between `.a` and `.d`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to adapt the [`flatten`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27009-flatten-nested-cell-arrays/content/flatten.m) function from the file exchange to use [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) so something like this:

```
function C = flatten_struct(A)

    A = struct2cell(A);
    C = [];
    for i=1:numel(A)  
        if(isstruct(A{i}))
            C = [C,flatten_struct(A{i})];
        else
            C = [C,A{i}]; 
        end
    end

end
```

This results in:

```
a.c = [5,4];
a.b.a=[9];
a.b.d=[1,2];

flatten_struct(a)

ans =

    5    4    9    1    2
```

So the order is in the order you declared your struct instead of in your example order which I presume is alphabetical. But you have control over this so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As noted there, this loses the structure names.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft who asked for the structure names? The desired output is a   1-d matrix of doubles.

Comment: there are other posts here and at mathworks where folks **do** want to keep the source names.  I'm not dissing your solution;  just warning other readers that there are tradeoffs.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but that has nothing to do with the question or this answer :/

Comment: Oh, well.  LABATYD

Answer (score -1):

I have a preliminary hack which does work but rather clumsily. It descends recursively, saving structure names **and** unpacking the returned structure at each "level" .

```
%  struct2sims converter
function simout = struct2sims(structin)
fnam = fieldnames(structin);
for jf = 1:numel(fnam)
    subnam = [inputname(1),'_',fnam{jf}];
    if isstruct(structin.(fnam{jf}) ) ,
    % need to dive;  build a new variable that's not a substruct
     eval(sprintf('%s = structin.(fnam{jf});', fnam{jf}));
    eval(sprintf('simtmp = struct2sims(%s);',fnam{jf}) );
    % try removing the struct before getting any farther...
    simout.(subnam) = simtmp;
    else
    % at bottom, ok
    simout.(subnam) = structin.(fnam{jf});
    end

end
 %  need to unpack structs here, after each level of recursion
 % returns...
    subfnam = fieldnames(simout);
    for kf = 1:numel(subfnam)
         if isstruct(simout.(subfnam{kf}) ),  
             subsubnam = fieldnames(simout.(subfnam{kf}));
             for fk = 1:numel(subsubnam)
                 simout.([inputname(1),'_',subsubnam{fk}])...
                     = simout.(subfnam{kf}).(subsubnam{fk}) ;
             end
             simout = rmfield(simout,subfnam{kf});
         end
    end
 % if desired write to file with:
 % save('flattened','-struct','simout');
end
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks -- really wow: someone read the fine print!  :-)